# Pre-Filling a ForeignKey from a link to the Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, foreign-keys

Some introduction. I have a "planet-like" feed aggregator with an extra layer on top. That extra layer allows for comments and elaboration on the aggregated posts. Here's some code for reference.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    published = models.DateTimeField()

class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    post = models.ForiegnKey(Post)
```

`Story` has a ForeignKey to `Post` and when I write a story I pick a post from the drop-down. Now, after a few weeks the list could get pretty unruly. I could use `raw_id_fields`, but that's a bit counter-intuitive since I would have to find the ID of the post I needed.

**EDIT**: After doing some research, I removed my misleading question. I'm wondering if something like this is possible (given that `application` is the name of my... application.

```
<a href="/admin/application/story/add/?post=[post.id]">Write about this post.</a>
```

Let me know if THIS needs any more explanation. :)

Comment: Up to the paragraph about what your problem is - managing a parent-child relationship on the django admin interface when you have too many Posts - I can follow you fine. I cannot understand what you mean by "specify the value of that ForeignKey via a link..."... Your question part is very undefined and I think that is the reason you got no responses up to now.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, the fact that I was a bit confused myself probably contributed to it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the admin recognizes GET values. So,

```
/admin/application/story/add/?post=[post.id]
```

would set `post` to the proper ID. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think about using an autocomplete field instead of raw_id_fields.

Jannis Leidel [has a good explanation](http://jannisleidel.com/2008/11/autocomplete-form-widget-foreignkey-model-fields/), with examples, on how to add auto-complete functionality to the djando admin exactly for cases like yours.

You will need to add jquery to the mix, but the process is not that complicated.